# How to evaluate this tough series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

How to evaluate

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty
>  }\frac{1}{n!k!}\frac{1}{n+k}\frac{\left [ \Gamma \left ( n+k \right )
>  \right ]^{3}}{\Gamma \left ( 2n+2k \right )}$$

my attempt:
$$I=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\Gamma \left ( k \right )\Gamma \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )}{k^{2}\Gamma \left ( k+\frac{1}{2} \right )}\,_3F_2\left ( k,k,k;k+1,k+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{4} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{k}$$
but after this, how to deal with this hypergeometric function? any idea?

Comment: Both summation indices cannot begin at $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate" in this case? Do you want a closed form in terms of special functions? In this case you have some connection to [Meijer G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function#Relationship_between_the_G-function_and_the_generalized_hypergeometric_function), see the linked series. Or maybe you just need a numerical value to high precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the integral representation of $_3F_2$
\begin{align*}
_3F_2\left ( a,b,c;d,e;z \right )=&\frac{\Gamma \left ( d \right )\Gamma \left ( e \right )}{\Gamma \left ( a \right )\Gamma \left ( b \right )\Gamma \left ( d-a \right )\Gamma \left ( e-b \right )}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{a-1}y^{b-1}\\
&\times \left ( 1-x \right )^{d-a-1}\left (  1-y\right )^{e-b-1}\left ( 1-xyz \right )^{-c}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}
we can perform the sum over $k$,
\begin{align*}
I&=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\Gamma \left ( k \right )\Gamma \left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )}{k^{2}\Gamma \left ( k+\dfrac{1}{2} \right )}\,_3F_2\left ( k,k,k;k+1,k+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{4} \right )\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{k}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k-1}y^{k-1}\left ( 1-y \right )^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{4}xy \right )^{-k}\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{k}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{xy\sqrt{1-y}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k}\left ( \frac{xy}{4-xy} \right )^{k}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{xy\sqrt{1-y}}\ln\left ( 1-\frac{xy}{4-xy} \right )\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{xy\sqrt{1-y}}\left [ \ln\left ( 1-\frac{xy}{4} \right )- \ln\left ( 1-\frac{xy}{2} \right )\right ]\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{Li}_2\left (\frac{y}{4}  \right )\mathrm{d}y+2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{Li}_2\left (\frac{y}{2}  \right )\mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}
For the first integral
\begin{align*}
-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{Li}_2\left (\frac{y}{4}  \right )\mathrm{d}y&=-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{1-y}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{y^{n}}{n^{2}}\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{n}\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{n}\int_{0}^{1}y^{n-1}\left ( 1-y \right )^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}}\frac{\Gamma \left ( n \right )\Gamma \left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )}{\Gamma \left ( n+\dfrac{1}{2} \right )}\left ( \frac{1}{4} \right )^{n}\\
&=-_4F_3\left (  1,1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2,2;\frac{1}{4}\right )\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\,_3F_2\left ( 1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{y}{4} \right )\mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}
In the last step we have used the integral representation of $_4F_3$ below
$$_4F_3\left (  a,b,c,d;e,f,g;z\right )=\frac{\Gamma \left ( g \right )}{\Gamma \left ( g-d \right )}\int_{0}^{1}x^{d-1}\left ( 1-x \right )^{g-d-1}\,_3F_2\left (a,b,c;e,f;zx  \right )\mathrm{d}x$$

By using the identity $(7.4.2.353)$ in ***Integral and series Vol.3*** and afterwards making the substitution $\dfrac{\sqrt{y}}{2}=\sin\dfrac{u}{2}$ we get
$$4\int_{0}^{1}\arcsin^{2}\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{3}}\frac{u^{2}}{2\tan\dfrac{u}{2}}\, \mathrm{d}u$$
Integration by part we get
$$2u^2\ln\left ( 2\sin\frac{u}{2} \right )\Bigg|_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{3}}-4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{3}}u\ln\left ( 2\sin\frac{u}{2} \right )\mathrm{d}u=-4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{3}}u\ln\left ( 2\sin\frac{u}{2} \right )\mathrm{d}u$$
Use the following identity in ***Polylogarithms and associated function***
$$\int_{0}^{\theta }\theta \ln\left ( 2\sin\frac{\theta }{2} \right )\mathrm{d}\theta =\mathrm{Li}_3\left ( 1 \right )-\theta \left [ \mathrm{Cl}_2\left ( \theta  \right )-\frac{1}{\pi } \right ]\mathrm{Cl}_3\left ( \theta  \right )$$
and
$$\mathrm{Cl}_3\left ( \frac{\pi }{3} \right )=\frac{1}{3}\zeta \left ( 3 \right )$$
we get 
$$-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{Li}_2\left (\frac{y}{4}  \right )\mathrm{d}y=\frac{8}{3}\zeta \left ( 3 \right )-\frac{4\pi }{3}\mathrm{Cl}_2\left ( \frac{\pi }{3} \right )$$
where $\mathrm{Cl}_n\left ( \cdot  \right )$ is [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function).

Now using the same way we get
\begin{align*}
2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{1-y}}\mathrm{Li}_2\left (\frac{y}{2}  \right )\mathrm{d}y&=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y\sqrt{1-y}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{y^{n}}{n^{2}}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{n}\mathrm{d}y\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{n}\int_{0}^{1}y^{n-1}\left ( 1-y \right )^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{d}y\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^{2}}\frac{\Gamma \left ( n \right )\Gamma \left ( \dfrac{1}{2} \right )}{\Gamma \left ( n+\dfrac{1}{2} \right )}\\
&=2\, _4F_3\left (  1,1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2,2;\frac{1}{2}\right )\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\,_3F_2\left ( 1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{y}{2} \right )\mathrm{d}y\\
&=4\int_{0}^{1}\arcsin^{2}\sqrt{\frac{y}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{u^{2}}{2\tan\dfrac{u}{2}}\, \mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{\pi ^{2}\ln2}{4}-4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}u\ln\left ( 2\sin\frac{u}{2} \right )\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{\pi ^{2}\ln2}{4}-\frac{35}{8}\zeta \left ( 3 \right )+2\pi \mathbf{G}
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{G}$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Now, combine the two part of the result, we will get the final answer of the tough series
$$\Large\boxed{\displaystyle \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty
 }\frac{1}{n!k!}\frac{1}{n+k}\frac{\left [ \Gamma \left ( n+k \right )
 \right ]^{3}}{\Gamma \left ( 2n+2k \right )}=-\frac{41}{24}\zeta \left ( 3 \right )-\frac{4\pi }{3}\mathrm{Cl}_2\left ( \frac{\pi }{3} \right )+\frac{\pi ^{2}\ln2}{4}+2\pi \mathbf{G}}}$$
 Using the same idea, we can easily get
 $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty
 }\frac{\left (  -1\right )^{k}}{n!k!}\frac{1}{n+k}\frac{\left [ \Gamma \left ( n+k \right )
 \right ]^{3}}{\Gamma \left ( 2n+2k \right )}=\frac{8}{3}\zeta \left ( 3 \right )-\frac{4\pi }{3}\mathrm{Cl}_2\left ( \frac{\pi }{3} \right )$$